# how to use firebase messaging 9.0 version latest versiom

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

i was tring to integrate new firebase messaging version dependancy

```
  firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
    print(" onLaunch called ${(msg)}");
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
    print(" onResume called ${(msg)}");
  },
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
    showNotification(msg);
    print(" onMessage called ${(msg)}");
  },
```

i am getting eroor lines in this point .configure

this is dart analysis error

> > The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging'.
> > Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'configure'.

Comment: Have you even looked at the flutter fire docs? https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/

Answer (score 2):

there are some changes in the library, delete what you mentioned and use this code instead within your initState function:

```
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      try {
        final data = message.data;
        print(message.notification);
        print(message.notification.title);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      try {
        print('onResume: $message');
        final data = message.data;
        print(message.notification);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    });
```

you should read the [changeLog](http://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/changelog)

Answer (score -1):

You need to import firebase messaging.